# How to store the output of an aggregate operator as a string in java?

Tags: java, aggregate-functions

I have a collection of airlines as follows:

```
        Airline airline1 = new Airline("Delta", "DC", 500, new Aircraft("b777-300"));
        Airline airline2 = new Airline("American", "Baltimore", 1000, new Aircraft("a330-200"));
        Airline airline3 = new Airline("Qatar", "Doha", 300, new Aircraft("b777-300"));

        Collection<Airline> airlines= new ArrayList<>();
        airlines.add(airline1);
        airlines.add(airline2);
        airlines.add(airline3);
```

how can I store one of those airlines' names as a string using the following aggregate operation (Mine is obviously wrong as it outputs a memory location when using System.out.println)?

```
String name = airlines
                    .stream()
                    .filter(a -> a.getName() == "American")
                    .toString();
```

Comment: Well, it depends. Do you want *all* the airlines with name "American" or just the first one?

Comment: In java we use `.equals()` method on `String`

Comment: @yami That's only *one* thing wrong here :P Another thing wrong is that they don't `collect` or `findFirst` on their stream (instead using `toString` which is not a good idea).

Comment: @Avi right, here I only need the only "American" one in the collection.

Comment: @MasoodS But if you only need the name of one airline, what is the point of the question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , I was trying to filter the objects and see if I have an "American". I know it's not the smartest way of doing it, but also tried to store the result as an object so that I can retrieve its city name later as well (which I haven't figured it out yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can fetch the single airline, or get a default string when it's not there:

```
String name = airlines                           // take the airlines
    .stream()                                    // stream them
    .filter(a -> a.getName().equals("American")) // take the one(s) with the name "American"
    .findFirst()                                 // get the first one if it's present
    .map(Object::toString)                       // use the toString method for the airline
    .orElse("Airline not found!");               // if no such airline, use this String
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
String allAirlines = airlines.stream()
                             .map(a -> a.getName())
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Rather than using `filter()`, which removes elements from the stream, you instead want to use `map()`, which finds the string name for each `Airline` object.  If you do want to filter airlines by name, then you could try:

```
String allAirlines = airlines.stream()
                             .filter(a -> a.startsWith("American"))
                             .map(a -> a.getName())
                             .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: If you have four "American Airlines" which fly to different destinations, you're going to get "American Airlines, American Airlines, American Airlines, American Airlines". That doesn't seem very good...

Comment: @Avi I have news for you: flying even once on American Airlines is bad enough.  El Al is way better IMHO.